What do we do about undegrad-level homework questions?
The following question,
Immunize portfolio with Bonds having restrictions Duration and Present Value?
appears to be an undergraduate-level introductory finance homework problem on bond immunization.  Judging by some previous meta questions, this is probably not in scope.  Anyone disagree?  Should we answer these basic questions (essentially all that is necessary to solve this guy's problem is applying the formulas he himself has provided in the question) or close them off?

Which question? I removed it already :P

As we can see from the other SE websites, an admission of questions with a tag homework not necessarily leads to bad outcomes - no matter what is the level of the homework. The only things that should be needed are

OP should write how did he try to solve this problem;
OP should write what where did he stack solving or thinking about the problem.

Sure, that's not the good idea just to solve the whole problem and give the whole solution. If a person writes that he doesn't know how to start, an admissible answer shouldn't be on the whole problem - just about how to start.
